# Implementing Fade in Fade Out on Array of Text in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I have an array of text that I'd like to iterate through and call the fadeIn and fadeOut functions in jQuery on.

```
var hellos = ["hi, i'm", "bonjour, je m'appelle", "hallo, ich heiße"]
```

The html code would look something like this:

```
<h2><span id="hellos"></span>Ch1maera</h2>
```

Ideally, on the front page of my website it would read something like "hi, i'm ch1maera" and then cycle through the different hellos, fading them in and then fading them out, while leaving "ch1maera" on the screen. If possible, I'd like to isolate the "ch1maera" from the hellos so that it stays in the same place and doesn't move depending on the length of the hellos in the list, if that makes sense. How would this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `text-align` of `h2` to `right` so that `Ch1maera` won't get moved by the hellos.

```js
var hellos = ["hi, i'm", "bonjour, je m'appelle", "hallo, ich heiße"];
var index = 0;                                // index of the currently displayed hello
$("#hellos").text(hellos[0]);                 // start by showing a hello

(function animate() {                         // the function responsibe for the animation
  $("#hellos").fadeOut(1000, function() {     // first fadeOut #hellos
    index = (index + 1) % hellos.length;      // when fadeOut complete, increment the index (check if go beyond the length of the array)
    this.textContent = hellos[index];         // change text accordingly
  }).fadeIn(1000, animate);                   // then fadeIn. When fadeIn finishes, call animate again
})();
```

```css
h2 {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><span id="hellos"></span> Ch1maera</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked great. One question I'd like to ask is. Why is it so that this only works with ID's and not classes? I tried changing $("#hellos") to $(".yourchosenclass") and the loop did not work. Can't figure it out.

Comment: @Pbalazs89 sorry for the late response. The class selector should work as well, just make sure you are selecting the right element. IDs are unique, whereas classes can be assigned to multiple elements at once, so you may be selecting another element with the same class and not the element you intend to.

Comment: Does anyone know why this could break when installed on AWS servers? It always stops after the second item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    var msg = ["Test Number 1", "Test Numero Dos", "Test, the third"];

$( document ).ready(function(){
    fade();
    setInterval(fade, 5000);
});

var i = 0;
function fade() {
  $('#message').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    i++;
    if(i>=msg.length)
    {
        i=0;
        
    }
    $('#message').html(msg[i])
    $('#message').fadeIn(1000)
 
  });
}
    
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="message" style="display:none;">TEST MESSAGE</div>

</body>
</html>
```